# loop over an object and return lowest number in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

So I'm a JS newbie and am trying to figure out how to fix my problem. I am trying to loop over an object and return the lowest number.

in my `var shortest = ;` if I hardcode a number say `var shortest = 455;` then the problem returns the correct number 3. although im not sure what to put there to make it blank by default. I have tried `object[0]`, `object[key]` and `''` and none of these work properly

```
var myObj = {first: 45, second: 23, third: 3, fourth: 222, fifth: 2343};

var myFunc = function (object) {
    var shortest = ;
    for (var key in object) {
      if (object[key] < shortest) {
        shortest = object[key];
      }
    }; 
    return shortest;
};
```

Comment: How about putting a really big number? How about `Infinity`? This question sure looks a lot like your previous one. Are these homework questions?

Comment: They are, just problems im creating trying to learn this lovely language :) I could hardcode the number, but that doesn't work in the real world, so trying to understand what the proper way to do it is.

Comment: Why doesn't it work in the real world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set initial value of shortest to Number.MAX_VALUE is all you need

```
var myObj = {first: 45, second: 23, third: 3, fourth: 222, fifth: 2343};

var myFunc = function (object) {
    var shortest = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var key in object) {
      if (object[key] < shortest) {
        shortest = object[key];
      }
    }; 
    return shortest;
};
```

**Number.MAX_VALUE
The largest positive representable number.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question. A bit more help would be to point out that when *x* is undefined, the result of `x < anyNumber` is always false (see [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5)) since *undefined* will be converted to `NaN`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. forget to handle undefined is a common source of bug :)

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I read the MDN doc and what does `MIN_value` mean as it said `Number.MIN_VALUEThe smallest positive representable number - that is, the positive number closest to zero (without actually being zero).` and I don't really get it. I ran it against my code and it gave back `5e-324` in the console.

Comment: @jstone 5e-324 is a float number: 5 multiply 0.1 324 times like: 0.000000005  you can read the detail here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Floating-point_literalsyou

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myObj = {first: 45, second: 23, third: 3, fourth: 222, fifth: 2343};

    var myFunc = function (object) {
        var shortest = object.first;
        for (var key in object) {
          if (object[key] < shortest) {
            shortest = object[key];
          }
        }; 
        return shortest;
    };
```

Comment: Given the use-case, it isn't safe to assume there is a key called `first`.

Comment: You'd really not want to hardcode a property. To take this approach, you'd need to initialize the variable in the first iteration of the loop, either using a flag, or by checking `shortest` for `undefined`.

Comment: You should not rely on setting *shortest* to some random value. What if `object.first === NaN` or `undefined`? Also, please explain answers rather than simply posting code.

Comment: Sorry for my English! But I just follow OP question. I think first key must be valid in this case. It's not random key, right?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fails is in here:

```
var myFunc = function (object) {
    var shortest = ;
    for (var key in object) {
      if (object[key] < shortest) {
```

Since the value of *shortest* is *undefined*, the `<` operator causes it to be converted to `NaN` for the test, and according to the rules for [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), comaring anything to `NaN` returns undefined, which is equivalent to `false` here.

The fix is to initialise *shortest* to some value, e.g. as qiu-deqing suggested Number.MAX_VALUE, or you can use something like:

```
function getShortest(object) {
    var shortest, value;

    for (var key in object) {
      value = object[key];

      if (typeof value == 'number' && !isNaN(value)) {

        if (typeof shortest != 'number') {
          shortest = value;
        } else {
          if (value < shortest) {
            shortest = value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return shortest;
}
```

The above will ensure that you only compare numbers and that *shortest* will only be a number or *undefined*. There should probably be a *hasOwnProperty* test too to avoid inherited properties.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
var lowest = function(ns) {
  return Math.min.apply(0, ns);
};

var values = function(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i in obj) {
    result.push(obj[i]);
  }
  return result;
};

var result = lowest(values(myObj));

console.log(result); //=> 3
```